# mysql_num_rows not returning 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that i cannot get to work and im not sure why.

```
$mysql = "QUERY";
$result = $conn->query($mysql);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "data";
}else{
    echo "";
}
```

No matter how I mix the > < != it will always show echo "";

Comment: [*"No matter how I mix the > <"* - Ironic.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: In case the link to the correct solution isn't 100% obvious; just replace `mysql_num_rows` with `mysqli_num_rows`